# Plotting readable graph with labels in networkx

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I want to plot a graph in networkx with 283 nodes and with labels. I don't know if it's even possible to do so, but i try with the following code:

```
def graph(list_edges,i):
    plt.figure(dpi=3000)    
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.title('Siatka nr {}'.format(i))
    edges=list_edges
    G=nx.Graph()
    G.add_edges_from(edges)
    pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
    nx.draw(G,pos,edge_color='black',width=1,linewidths=1,\
        node_size=5,node_color='pink',alpha=0.9,\
        #labels={node:node for node in G.nodes()},\
        font_size=3)
    plt.savefig("plot__tr__{}.png".format(i), dpi=3000)

graph(edges,0)
```

I've tried to play with dpi, but i doesn't help.
With commented out labels I get: [image]

Is it somehow possible to force better distribution of nodes and add labels on one image and keep readbility? Or maybe there is an option to plot whole image in parts (which would also be helpful in my situation)?

Answer (score 0):

Hey I am unsure about how to plot the whole image in parts or how to get a better distribution of nodes, however; if you want to add labels to your nodes, this should solve your problem: 
- Add `with_labels=True` as an argument when you draw your network. Hope this helps.

e.g

```
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
```